# How to pass data to props from state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and have some troubles with using state and props. There is two files: App.js and component. In App.js i use axios to get JSON data from IP and store in a state. But I cannot pass the data to props through the state.
Here is App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Shutruk from './Shutruk';

const qwerty = {
  "data": [
      {
          "_id": "5d1cb18e4af03042df6267c5",
          "title": "Shutruk",
          "description": "Shhhhhhhhhhhhh",
          "date": "2019-07-03T13:45:50.850Z",
          "__v": 0
      },
      {
          "_id": "5d1cc27b37c9751001f5c12f",
          "title": "Shilkhak",
          "description": "Shilkhak-Inshushinak",
          "date": "2019-07-03T14:58:03.797Z",
          "__v": 0
      },
      {
          "_id": "5d1cc45655780f11112a023f",
          "title": "Унташ",
          "description": "Untash-Napirisha",
          "date": "2019-07-03T15:05:58.699Z",
          "__v": 0
      },
      {
          "_id": "5d1ef36c503601183b5f856f",
          "title": "dgfdgfdhgf",
          "description": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
          "date": "2019-07-05T06:51:24.873Z",
          "__v": 0
      },
      {
          "_id": "5d1ef381503601183b5f8570",
          "title": "qewytuytruytru",
          "description": "jhfgasjdfgasjdfgjhsdf",
          "date": "2019-07-05T06:51:45.761Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  ]
};
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5555/posts')
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        this.setState({ data });
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Shutruk name={ this.state.data.data[0].title }/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Shutruk extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is is {this.props.name}!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Shutruk;
```

I use axios to get data from backend, but when I insert it to props, it does'nt work. I create an array qwerty[] with the same data, and when I replace with:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Shutruk name={ qwerty.data[0].title }/>
  </div>
)
```

it works correctly. What is the problem, if there is no difference between 'this.state.data' and 'qwerty'?
I checked with console.log and the result is same!
Thanks to everyone for any help!

Comment: Try putting 'this.state.data' in a variable and then read title from that variable like -
var dataResponse = this.state.data;
and then pass dataResponse.data[0].title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, axios and setState are asynchronous and when the component loads in componentDidMount, it takes a while to load data into state and since data.data[0] is still empty, it doesn't work. But when you use a const to declare it, it works as it is already present.

Instead of

`<Shutruk name={ this.state.data.data[0].title }/>`

Do:

```
  renderShutruk = () => {
    if (this.state.data.data !== undefined) {
      return <Shutruk name={this.state.data.data[0].title} />
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderShutruk()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this,

```
<Shutruk name={ this.state.data.data[0].title }/>
```

with,

```
{this.state.data ? <Shutruk name={ this.state.data[0].title }/> : null}
```

**Update**

If you are not getting data, then you must use `async/await`,

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:5555/posts')
      .then(res => {
        //console.log(res) => if `res` is {data:[...]} , then do this,
        const data = res.data;
        //console.log(res) => if `res` is {data: data: [...]} , then do this,
        const data = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ data });
      })
  }
```

Comment: It does'nt help (((
TypeError: this.state.data[0] is undefined
(((

Comment: Also try to print `res.data`

Answer (score 1):

Your `App` component is probably crashing when mounting while you're accessing an undefined state because your try to get `this.state.data.data[0].title` when `data` state equals `[]`

Try replacing your `App` component like this to prevent access to an undefined state (I recommend doing this for all your asynchronous operations in the components):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    loading: true,
    error: false,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5555/posts')
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data.data; // get the data array instead of object
        this.setState({ data, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(err => { // log request error and prevent access to undefined state
        this.setState({ loading: false, error: true });
        console.error(err); 
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return(
        <div>
          <p> Loading... </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    if (this.state.error || !this.state.data[0]) { // if request failed or data is empty don't try to access it either
      return(
        <div>
          <p> An error occurred </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Shutruk name={ this.state.data[0].title }/> // access to data array state
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Glad it helps, I hope you understood the code and the reason behind it.
You can accept my answer if it meets your expectations.